# Is aircrack-ng compatible with Intel pro/wireless 3945abg

Tags: aircrack-ng

I just want to know if I install aircrack-ng if it will work on my Intel pro/wireless 3945abg computer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the intel 3945 card uses the iwl3945 driver that is included into kernel and it supports packet injection and monitoring mode that is used by aircrack-ng.

If you (somehow) don't have that driver installed run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-firmware`